# Prove $A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A+B)^{-1}A$ where $(A+B)^{-1}$ and $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ matricies.

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

Hi I have been working on this problem for the longest time.

Prove:

$ A(A+B)^{-1}B = B(A + B)^{-1}A$

We know that A & B exist in real space, and that they are also N x N matrices. It is also given that $(A + B)^{-1}$ is true. We do not know anything about A or B however except that their sum is invertible.

I was going to use the SMW Identity but the issue is that you need to assume that either A or B is invertible which we cannot assume in this case.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Proceed as follows:
$$
A(A+B)^{-1}B =\\
[(A + B) - B](A+B)^{-1}B =\\
(A + B)(A+B)^{-1}B - B(A+B)^{-1}B=\\
B - B(A+B)^{-1}B =\\
B - B(A+B)^{-1}[(A + B) - A] =\\
B - [B(A+B)^{-1}(A + B) - B(A+B)^{-1}A]=\\
B - [B - B(A+B)^{-1}A]=\\
B(A+B)^{-1}A
$$

Comment: Thanks... I spent about 4 hours doing this. Omnomnomnomnom is a hero amongst men.

Comment: @Nic That's a new one for me :) Glad to help!